# Uploading image to GitHub via API in Node.js

Tags: node.js, image, github, github-api, fs

We have an image on the local disk called image.jpg or image.png that we upload to GitHub using this code:

```
let request = require('request');
let fs = require('fs');
let filepath = 'image.png' // or image.jpg
let options = 
{
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path',
  body: {
    message: "pls work",
    content: Buffer.from(fs.readFileSync(filepath, 'binary')).toString('base64'),
  },
  json: true,
  auth: {
    user: 'ourusername',
    pass: 'ourpass'
  },
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': 'ourusername'
  }
}

request(options,
  function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
    } else {
      console.log('SUCCESS', body);
    }
  }
);
```

We had similar code that worked perfectly for text files but for images we are ending up with files on GitHub like:

```
bXYZ@dmndTpdmddÄvuedLviewÔ$lumiømeas$tech0rTRC<gTRC<bTRC...
```

I believe it has something to do with the reading in binary or base64, but encoding is still new to me and we can't figure out how to make the images come out correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've asked a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61553399/how-can-i-save-a-valid-image-to-github-using-their-api and it appears that GitHub API does not support upload of images as they can only accept encoding of utf-8 and base64 https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb/issues/986