# Save a base64 Data URL of an image as image using Github API in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, github-api

I have a base64 Data URL of a webp image in the format `data:image/webp;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=`

I want to commit it to github using the API in the format of a webp image.

To make it more clear, what I want to archive [this](https://github.com/learntheropes/img-test/blob/main/learntheropes.png).

But what I archive is [this](https://github.com/learntheropes/img-test/blob/main/ad63ba74-5205-4a89-9f59-a5448bdc729f.webp) or [this](https://github.com/learntheropes/img-test/blob/main/aa637a8a-10c4-46e4-a604-e8456f466f48.webp).

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576040/11258206) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71201317/11258206) it should be possible but so far all my test failed.

I'm using ofetch that is wrapper for fetch in javascript, but that works with json files. My issue is that I think to need to convert the data to something else first.

So far my code is:

```js
    import { ofetch } from 'ofetch';
    
    const path = 'random_name.webp';
    const message = 'random commit message';
    const data = `data:image/webp;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=`;
    const content = data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, '');

    await ofetch(`/repos/learntheropes/img-test/contents/${path}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      baseURL: 'https://api.github.com',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
        Authorization: `token OMITTED`
      },
      body: {
        message,
        content;
      },
      async onRequestError({ request, error }) {
        console.log('[fetch request error]', request, error);
      },
      async onResponseError({ request, response }) {
        console.log('[fetch response error]', request, response.status, response.body);
      }
    })
```

I also tried to convert the string to a blob but the request get rejected:

```js
const dataURLtoBlob = (data) => {

  const arr = data.split(',');
  const mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
  const bstr = atob(arr[1]);
  let n = bstr.length;
  let u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);

  while(n--){
    u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
  }

  return new Blob([u8arr], {
    type:mime
  });
}

 const content = dataURLtoBlob(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out how to convert the data:

```js
const data = `data:image/webp;base64,R0lGODdhAQABAPAAAP8AAAAAACwAAAAAAQABAAACAkQBADs=`;
const binaryImageData = atob(data.split(',')[1]);
const content = btoa(binaryImageData)
```

Then you can PUT it as described in the question.